# How to filter items by user in data form web part

Tags: data-form-web-part

We created a customized data form  web part, and there are some items don't want user with specified permission level (or group) to view.

Could give some help on how to do this, or whether we could do this in data form web part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have setup User Profile Syncronization. There is a Filter Web Part for that, which should be able to benefit you from the Connectable web parts framework. Have a look here to see how is being used http://www.bjw.co.nz/developer/sharepoint-2010/97-using-a-current-user-filter-on-a-list

To filter out items based on assigned permissions you could use the extension function in ddwrt: ifHasRights example here http://sharepointjim.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/sharepoint-data-view-conditional-formatting-based-on-user-permissions-ifhasrights/

Otherwise you can only do it by code.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I want, I don't want to filter data by people column. There are some items status is like "Pending", and the users in final user group should not view them.

Comment: not sure ootb you can achieve it, close to what you want i've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, you open a new window for me:) Could I ask is there any ddwrt to check whether the user is in a group?

Comment: All available functions are here explained http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(v=office.11).aspx, and NO there is not, but you could extend it yourself see here http://blog.mastykarz.nl/extending-content-query-web-part-xslt-custom-functions/ (same principles apply to DVWP or XVWP)